# jQuery remove/add class only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm lacking on sleep and unsure if I could use toggleClass for this. But here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Slide Mobile Filter Sidebar On Screen
    $('#showFilters').on('click', function () {
        $('.filter-sidebar--mobile__close').attr('class', 'filter-sidebar--mobile__close');

        $('.filter-sidebar--mobile')
            .removeClass('slide-out-right is-hidden') // Remove previously added animation remove display none
            .addClass('slide-in-right '); // Add animation
    });

    // Slide Mobile Filter Sidebar Off Screen
    $('.filter-sidebar--mobile__close').on('click', function() {
        $('.filter-sidebar--mobile')
            .addClass('slide-out-right') // Add animation
            .delay(380) // Delay for animation duration -.02s
            .queue(function() {
                $('.filter-sidebar--mobile').addClass('is-hidden'); // Hide after animation finishes
            });

        // Hide Close Button for Mobile Filter
        $('.filter-sidebar--mobile__close').attr('class', 'filter-sidebar--mobile__close is-hidden');
    });
});
```

This code only works through one full cycle. 

What happens is;

- On load: no mobile filter(as expected)
- Click #showFilters button
- .filter-sidebar--mobile slides in from the right (as expected)
- Click .filter-sidebar--mobile__close, .filter-sidebar--mobile slides out to the right (as expected)
- Click #showFilters button again
- .filter-sidebar--mobile slides in from the right (again as expected)
- Click .filter-sidebar--mobile__close, .filter-sidebar--mobile animation plays, however this time does not stay hidden

[Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mfayv8fu/](https://jsfiddle.net/mfayv8fu/)

Comment: please make a working demo

Comment: Working demo as per [mcve]

Comment: in the `queue() call`, `$('filter-sidebar--mobile').addClass('is-hidden');` should be `$('.filter-sidebar--mobile').addClass('is-hidden');`

Comment: @brk I added one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/queue/) Documentation :

> Note that when adding a function with .queue(), we should ensure that .dequeue() is eventually called so that the next function in line executes.

So, in the queue callback, your code should be :

```
$('.filter-sidebar--mobile')
    .addClass('is-hidden')
    .dequeue();
```

Or :

> As of jQuery 1.4, the function that's called is passed another function as the first argument. When called, this automatically dequeues the next item and keeps the queue moving. We use it as follows:

```
.queue(function(next) {
    $('.filter-sidebar--mobile').addClass('is-hidden'); // Hide after animation finishes
    next();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the dot sign in querying your classes

```
  $('filter-sidebar--mobile').addClass('is-hidden');
```

change it to

```
  $('.filter-sidebar--mobile').addClass('is-hidden');
```